# How to make a spiral track less aggressive near the start and end

Tags: bezier-curves

I've imported an FBX file form the Unity karting microgame learning project and am trying to reproduce their spiraling track. So far, I've managed to deduce that they used a bezier curve and then a bevel object to make the track. When using an Archimedean spiral, I can get a close match to what they have using the same technique.

However, the start and end of my track still spiral up and the whole track goes up a a continuous rate. Even though the 4 "quarter circle vertices" (90deg points) match up perfectly, the vertices in between differ in height on the original object, leading to a smoother entry and exit. How do I achieve this result?

See attached pictures for their version in purple, mine in gray and the overlap from 2 viewpoints.
[image: their track]
[image: my track]
[image: overlap-front]
[image: overlap-side]
[image: curve using bevel object]

Comment: Match the bezier, and change the end points at the top and bottom to be flat

Comment: Use a *Screw* modifier instead.

Comment: Marcel: How would I go about doing that? Changing the end points to be flat only affects the very end and keeps the rest of the spiral "aggressive" rather than smoothing into it.

Comment: Duarte: I tried that too, it gives the same result as the screw goes up with a constant increment in height, just like the Archimedean spiral.

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you meant, I though you were taking about the start and end faces not being vertical. In that case it seems obvious what Marcello suggested, just tweak the bezier points to match your desire slope, possibly using proportional edit

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos No worries, thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried it with proportional edit, but because the 4 "corners" already match up, they should keep their locations. So I find it hard to use proportional edit to fix each quarter circle.

It keeps bumping up or down the corners, which is not desired.

Comment: It seems to me the original object creator managed to create a spiral with some form of "smooth entry/exit" tool. As the points at 0, 90, 180, 270, 360deg do match up perfectly with an evenly distributed spiral, just the vertices in between are distributed differently on the Z-axis without being jagged at the 90def points. It almost seems too smooth to have been done manually with proportional editing.

Comment: Your spiral seems to have an unnecessarily high number of points, making it hard to edit. Try reducing to the minimum required to get a smooth spiral

Comment: Yeah I added that many points because the original object has a lot of vertices in it. So I tried to match it as closely as possible as I thought that might be the key to smoothing out the entry/exit.  The thing that puzzles me the most is that it all lines up so neatly. So they somehow selected all the points and said "start slowly, then ramp up", all the while keeping the 4 corner points untouched. You'd figure if they proportionally edited each quadrant individually, that it would be a bit weird/jagged at the 4 90-degree points.

Comment: Instead of increasing the number of control points, which defeats the purpose of bezier curves, you can tweak the Resolution inside of the curve data in the properties panel (green icon with 2 dots and an arc)

Comment: Oh thanks @Gorgious I had no idea you were supposed to use bezier curves like that. I can't seem to find the Resolution, though. Right now, with few points, the spiral is looking very blocky. Am I supposed to set it on the bezier curve or the curve I use as the bevel?

Comment: Hmm, the resolution only works when I add a spiral using Bezier with Auto handles, with Vector handles it does nothing whatsoever and I need to increase the amount of points to improve the quality. But with Auto handles, the inner circle's quality is terrible. Only happens when using Z-Up

Comment: You can do it with 3 control points : Tweak the tilt of the 3rd point to line it perfectly, Check this file : https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/zDKWgrYo